# Change Craft 3 password algorithm

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

Is there a way to specify in Craft 3 which hashing algorithm should passwords use?
I know craft 3 uses PHP's `password_hash()` function, my question is: is there a way of modifying the 2nd and 3rd parameter of that function via a craft config.

I'm trying to find a way of doing this without using a separate/custom column in the users table.

Thank you.

Comment: You're looking to use PASSWORD_ARGON2I instead of bcrypt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd parameter for the hash cost you can control via the [blowfishHashCost](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#property-blowfishhashcost) config setting.

The 2nd parameter (for the algorithm) is a bit more difficult because it's not exposed via a config setting. I assume you want to use PASSWORD_ARGON2I since that and PASSWORD_BCRYPT 
 (the default) are the only two options: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

You'd need to create a custom [Application Config](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/configuration.html#application-config) component that overrode Craft's `security` component with your own Security class.  Your own class could extend Craft's an overwrite just the `hashPassword` method, or any others that you might need to.

Comment: The 3rd parameter doesn't only consist of the cost, if I want to customize the salt generation, Craft doesn't provide a config for that. So the best way to do this is indeed to rewrite the Security class.